# How to get values from ArrayList<String[]>

Tags: java

How to get or print String from `ArrayList<String[]>`?

```
ArrayList<String[]> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
arrayList.add(new String[]{"A1","A1","A3"});
arrayList.add(new String[]{"B1","B1","B3"});
arrayList.add(new String[]{"C1","C1","C3"});

System.out.println("*** 1 ***");
System.out.println(arrayList);

System.out.println("*** 2 ***");
for (int i = 0; i < arrayList.size(); i++) {
    System.out.println((String[])arrayList.get(i));
}

System.out.println("*** 3 ***");
for (int i = 0; i < arrayList.size(); i++) {
    System.out.println(arrayList.get(i).toString());
}

System.out.println("*** 4 ***");
for (int i = 0; i < arrayList.size(); i++) {
    String[] strings = arrayList.get(i);
    System.out.println(strings);
}
```

output:

```
*** 1 ***
[[Ljava.lang.String;@2a85f3d6, [Ljava.lang.String;@404b7c69, [Ljava.lang.String;@1bd4f279]

*** 2 ***
[Ljava.lang.String;@2a85f3d6
[Ljava.lang.String;@404b7c69
[Ljava.lang.String;@1bd4f279
*** 3 ***
[Ljava.lang.String;@2a85f3d6
[Ljava.lang.String;@404b7c69
[Ljava.lang.String;@1bd4f279
*** 4 ***
[Ljava.lang.String;@2a85f3d6
[Ljava.lang.String;@404b7c69
[Ljava.lang.String;@1bd4f279
```

Comment: Perhaps you need two loops?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sadly, java's default `toString()` for arrays is useless. You must use the utility method [`Arrays.toString()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#toString%28java.lang.Object%5B%5D%29). This will work:

```
for (String[] strings : arrayList)
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(strings));
```

Answer (score 2):

In Java, each *object* has [`toString()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString%28%29) method, the default is displaying the class name representation, then adding `@` and then the hashcode.

`strings` is an *array* of `String`s. You should use [`Arrays#toString()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#toString%28int%5B%5D%29), which is implemented [this way](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/Arrays.java#Arrays.toString%28int%5B%5D%29) (I advise you to go through it to better understand what's going on):

```
3860     public static String toString(int[] a) { {
3861        if (a == null)
3862            return "null";
3863        int iMax = a.length - 1;
3864        if (iMax == -1)
3865            return "[]";
3866
3867        StringBuilder b = new StringBuilder();
3868        b.append('[');
3869        for (int i = 0; ; i++) {
3870            b.append(a[i]);
3871            if (i == iMax)
3872                return b.append(']').toString();
3873            b.append(", ");
3874        }
3875    }
```

Or, you can loop on it and manually print the items:

```
for(String str: strings) {
    System.out.println(str + " ");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to modify this :

```
**@Override
public String toString() {
    return "abc [name=" + name + ", stage=" + stage
            + ", messageCode=" + messageCode + ", title=" + title
            + ", description=" + description + ", expiryTimeLeft="
            + expiryTimeLeft + ", holdLimit=" + holdLimit + ", points="
            + points];
}
```